# I want the "Add" button to be enabled on my page after the user has selected the first option from dropdown menu

Tags: html, angular

On my page, the user must first choose an option from the dropdown menu. Up on selection of any option, the "Add" and "Go" button should be enabled and on clicking the "add" button the user must be allowed to enter another field apart from the one already picked. Please help me on how to add this functionality using Angular2.
I have attached the html and typescript code below

Filter By:

```
            <div class="dropdown">
                <select class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="options" data-toggle="dropdown">
             <span class="caret"></span>
                    <option *ngFor="let feature of features" class="dropdown-menu-item">
                        {{feature}}
                    <option>
                </select>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default disabled ">Add</button>
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-default disabled ">Go</button>
```

typescript code like this:

```
export class SE {

    description = 'SE';
    features: string[];



    constructor(){
        this.features = [
            'AL',
            'CP',
            'FI',
            'HD',
            'Se'
       ];



    }
```

along with the link to the static page currently. On the page, after an option is selected, the buttons should get enabled.
The "Add" button should allow us to choose options from one more dropdown menu with set of options as previous menu apart from the one already selected.
The "Go" button should allow user to submit his entry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to create an object with all of your options in the drop-down menu and you should create an array of those objects. (firstly there would be only one object) Then as described in the previous answers, you can enable the buttons upon the selection. Once the add button is clicked, you should add another new options object to that array. Another array to keep selections. This would work. (I have not tested it though).

```
<select *ngFor='let featureSet of featureSets; let i=index' class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="options" data-toggle="dropdown" (change)="OnDropdownItemSelected($event.target.value,i)">
     <span class="caret"></span>
            <option *ngFor="let feature of featureSet" class="dropdown-menu-item" value="{{feature}}">
                {{feature}}
            <option>
        </select> 
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default disabled " (click)='onAddClick()'>Add</button>
```

in the component ts

```
export class SecurityExceptions {

    description = 'Security Exceptions';

    selections: string[];

    featureSets: any[];

    constructor(){
         this.selections=[];
         this.featureSets=[];
         this.addFeatures();
    } 
    onAddClick(){ 
    this.addFeatures(); 
    }

    addFeatures(){
    this.featureSets.push([
                    'Application',
                    'Cusip',
                    'Funds Impacted',
                    'Holdings Date',
                    'Security'
               ]);
    }

    OnDropdownItemSelected(value:string,i:number){ 
    if(this.selections[i]){
            this.selections[i]=value;
        } else{
        this.selections.push(value);
        }
    }
```

Comment: could you pleasse explain the way in which this works. cause itried it and it does. But im not able to understand the reason behind 2 for loops and also what the this.featureSets.push is actually doing. its working fine , just need to understand this. So then i can depopulate the successive dropdown from the options already selected. Help would be really appreciated. seem to be stuck

Comment: 1st `*ngFor` in the `<select>` loads the number of dropdowns needs to be added upon the user's clicking on the `Add` button.
2nd `ngFor` in the `<option>` loads the items in each drop down.  `featureSets` array stores data objects for all drop-downs. It contains a set of objects of items that need to be there in each drop-down. Thus `this.featureSets.push()` is adding an item set to the array each time the user clicks on the `Add` button.

Comment: For the second question about depopulating, you can keep a separate items object and remove elements upon user's selection so that `featureSets.push()` will only add the available items in that object. And please mark as the answer if the solution works. Thanks

Comment: thanks very much for the clarification, now can use it. For the part of depopulating selected item already, does your sol. mean that(if im thinking of it in exact way as you)  the data value  that we are assigning to the `selections` array in the `OnDropdownItemSelected(value:string,i=number)` function must be pushed from the `featureSets` array into a new array(which is empty)and must  contain item objects. So that next time the `this.featureSets.push()` adds the item set to next dropdown only the remaining values from that array will remain.
Please let me know if thinking on the right terms

Comment: simply declare an array object `items: any[];` and assign it with the items object in the constructor `this.items=['Application', 'Cusip', 'Funds Impacted',                     'Holdings Date', 'Security']` so in the `addFeatures()`, `this.featureSets.push(this.items);`. When a user selects a particular item, remove that item from `items`

Comment: Hi Nadun , the solution worked. and it turns out that depopulating is not required. So if you could please delete the previous comment or make changes to the words as i have done in the question would be really nice. As this is currently a page not to be disclosed to anyone outside at all

Answer (score 0):

First of all define **change Event** on dropdown:

```
 <select class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="options" data-toggle="dropdown" (change)="OnDropdownItemSelected($event.target.value)">
         <span class="caret"></span>
                <option *ngFor="let feature of features" class="dropdown-menu-item" value="{{feature}}">
                    {{feature}}
                <option>
            </select>
```

Then at component level check value and Enable and Disabled button as per requirement:

```
let isDisabled:boolean=true;

public OnDropdownItemSelected(value:any):void{
     this.isDisabled=true;
     if(value!=null && value!='')
     {
         this.isDisabled=false;
     }
}
```

On **button** set **Enabled/Disabled Condition**:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" [disabled]="isDisabled">Add</button>
```

OR **assign disable class**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" [ngClass]="isDisabled?'disabled':''">Add</button>
```

Comment: hi this helped a bit.(ie- it helped activate the "add" button after choosing anoption from drop-down menu) i can now similarly activate the "go" button. But further doubt/hurdle is that on clicking the "add" button, the user must be able to choose from another separate drop-down menu(having almost same options as last menu) and then choose to add further or submit. 
So basically my new doubt is, how do i enable another dropdown menu in the same line after the user selects "Add". Please help. Thanks in advance Sandip.

Comment: Define other variable to enabled your second dropdown/other control and in current  dropdown selection change Event you can check with selected value and based on that update new variable and apply something similar above logic.

Comment: i was thinking that using the ng-click directive along with the ng-repeat would allow me to repeat the list in a new drop-down menu when the user clicks on "add" button. But i am struggling a bit to implement it. Could you help out here

Answer (score 0):

give a try on this

```
 <div class="dropdown">
                    <select #mydropdown class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="options" data-toggle="dropdown">
                 <span class="caret"></span>
    <option [ngValue]="0">Select</option>                                                                                 <option *ngFor="let feature of features" class="dropdown-menu-item">{{feature}}</option>
                    </select>
              <button type="button" [disabled]="mydropdown.value='0'" class="btn btn-default disabled ">Add</button>
               <button type="button" class="btn btn-default disabled ">Go</button>
```